# Laravel 5 Fetching Relation Data from other table without using pivot

Tags: laravel, database-relations

I have the following table structure.

**Posts**

- id (int)
- title (varchar)
- comments (json field)

**Comments**

- id
- title

The comments field looks like following (It's a simple array of ids):

```
[6, 9, 48, 12, 49]
```

Now I want to query the `Posts` and replace all ids in comments with the values of the `Comments` table.

Can I do this without using a pivot table like in laravel relations (`belongsToMany`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your table structure like this:

Posts

```
id (int)
title (varchar)
```

Comments

```
id
title
post_id
```

This way you will have simple hasMany relation without any pivot tables.

Comment: Okey thanks seems like a good solution. And what would my query look like ?
E.g. Post::find(1);
What are the additional methods to get all comments for this post ?

Comment: Just simple relation `$post->comments` will return array of comment models